# C++ need help, random switch statements

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code which is kind of like a fortune teller but I'm having some trouble with my switch statements. When executed the code prints out the same message and doesn't pick a random case like its supposed to! can someone please help me! thank you!
heres my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void printGreeting(); // function prototype

int main()
{
    int choice;
    printGreeting();
    cout << "Would you like to see your fortune?" << endl;
    cout << "Press 1 to see your fortune or 2 if you don't!" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        cout << "Great! Your fortune is: ";
        // Function to generate random number
        void rand1();
        srand(time(NULL));
        int MAX_NUM;
        MAX_NUM = 5;
        int random = rand() % MAX_NUM;
        cout << random << endl;

        int selection;
        selection = 5;

        switch (selection)
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "Change can hurt, but it leads a path to something better!";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "If you have something good in your life don't let it go!";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "You're in for a treat today.";
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "Land is always on the mind of a flying bird";
                break;
            case 5:
                cout << "A dream you have will come true";
                break;
        }

        return 0;
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        cout << "Okay goodbye!" << endl;
    }
}

// Prints greeting message
void printGreeting() // function header
{
    cout << "Hello! Welcome to your fortune teller!" << endl; // function body
}
```

Comment: Debug your code always. Step through and see what is the value of `random` and which case statement is being called? You would have figured out this way by yourself.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Maybe you should use the random number you generated for the selection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `selection = 5;`

You want to choose `selection` with a random value between 1 - 5, right?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i need it to do.

Comment: Hi @Zain N., if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: `selection = rand() % 5 + 1; // selection in the range 1 to 5` . Read more about generating random numbers [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ZainN. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: better use the functions from <random>

Answer (score 0):

You switch by `selection` variable, which is explicitly set to 5 right before the switch itself. Consider switching by `random` variable.